# SQL query based on foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, a Project and an Action:

Project has the following fields:

```
project_name
```

Action has the following fields:

```
action_name
project
status
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between Action and Project.

I need a query that returns all the Projects that ONLY have actions with statuses greater than 1 OR Projects with no actions at all.

I've never written a query that is dependent on a relationship.  How might this be constructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution seems correct. Here's another way that may be more efficient as it doesn't do a grouping. It can't show the `MIN(status)` though:

```
SELECT
    "id", "name" 
FROM 
    "testapp_project" AS p
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM "testapp_action" AS a
          WHERE p."id" = a."project_id"
            AND a."status" <= 1 
        ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    "testapp_project"."id", "testapp_project"."name", 
    MIN("testapp_action"."status") AS "m" 
FROM 
    "testapp_project" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "testapp_action" ON
        ("testapp_project"."id" = "testapp_action"."project_id")
    GROUP BY "testapp_project"."id", "testapp_project"."name" 
    HAVING(
       MIN("testapp_action"."status") IS NULL 
         OR
       MIN("testapp_action"."status") > 1 
    )
```